# Invalidate session if user is set to inactive in meanwhile - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, session

Symfony - 2.8.4
FOSRestBundle

I have problem with session based login system. My User class implements `AdvancedUserInterface`, `\Serializable` and it looks like this :

```
/** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize([
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        $this->isActive,
    ]);
}

/** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        $this->isActive,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
}
...
public function isEnabled()
{
    return $this->isActive;
}
```

So there is property isActive responsible for checking if user can access app. This is all working when user want's to login but problem is if user has been logged into app and somebody else set him to be inactive. User still can make ajax calls to API. From symfony doc :

> Once the user is logged in, the entire User object is serialized into
>   the session. On the next request, the User object is deserialized.
>   Then, the value of the id property is used to re-query for a fresh
>   User object from the database. Finally, the fresh User object is
>   compared to the deserialized User object to make sure that they
>   represent the same user. For example, if the username on the 2 User
>   objects doesn't match for some reason, then the user will be logged
>   out for security reasons.

Even if I debug that code, User from session have inActive:1 and from DB there is value 0 and it goes to `$changed = true`

```
/**
 * Sets the user in the token.
 *
 * The user can be a UserInterface instance, or an object implementing
 * a __toString method or the username as a regular string.
 *
 * @param string|object $user The user
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function setUser($user)
{
    if (!($user instanceof UserInterface || (is_object($user) && method_exists($user, '__toString')) || is_string($user))) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$user must be an instanceof UserInterface, an object implementing a __toString method, or a primitive string.');
    }

    if (null === $this->user) {
        $changed = false;
    } elseif ($this->user instanceof UserInterface) {
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            $changed = true;
        } else {
            $changed = $this->hasUserChanged($user);
        }
    } elseif ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
        $changed = true;
    } else {
        $changed = (string) $this->user !== (string) $user;
    }

    if ($changed) {
        $this->setAuthenticated(false); //GOES HERE !!!
    }

    $this->user = $user;
}
```

And after that response is returned normally like if user is logged in. But documentation previously quoted said that will destroy that session and user will be logged out :(

Is this a bug? Have anyone had same issue

Thanks in advance